# Can't get my images in html to show and position the way i want

Tags: image, position, styles, overlay

What I am trying to do is to get three images in the same position but I can't get them to line up. 
The images also will not load and I have yet to finger out why as they have the correct name and path.

```
<h5 id="energyWorkers" style="display:none">Energy workers</h5>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <img id="energyWorkersProgressBackground" scr="‪Assets\loading-bar-background.jpg" style="width:10%;height:52px;position:relative;top:0;left:0">
        <img id="energyWorkersBar" scr="‪Assets\loading-bar-fill-pur.jpg" style="width:10%;height:15px;position:absolute;top:0;left:5">
        <img id="energyWorkersProgressFrame" scr="‪Assets\loading-bar-background.jpg" style="width:10%;height:52px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
    </div>
    <button onclick="setWorkerJob('energy', 1)" id="energyWorkers+" style="display:none;float:left">+</button>
    <button onclick="stopWorkerJob('energy', 1)" id="energyWorkers-" style="display:none">-</button>
</div>
```

[images of what I am getting with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YbpV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Give relative z index for div and image as follows.

```
<h5 id="energyWorkers" style="display:none">Energy workers</h5>
<div style="position:relative; z-index:-1">
    <img id="energyWorkersProgressBackground" scr="‪Assets\loading-bar-background.jpg" style="width:10%;height:52px;position:relative;top:0;left:0; z-index:1">
    <img id="energyWorkersBar" scr="‪Assets\loading-bar-fill-pur.jpg" style="width:10%;height:15px;position:absolute;top:0;left:5; z-index:1">
    <img id="energyWorkersProgressFrame" scr="‪Assets\loading-bar-background.jpg" style="width:10%;height:52px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0; z-index:1">
</div>
<button onclick="setWorkerJob('energy', 1)" id="energyWorkers+" style="display:none;float:left">+</button>
<button onclick="stopWorkerJob('energy', 1)" id="energyWorkers-" style="display:none">-</button>
```

Please reproduce this if you can and attach a link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried implementing this but it did nothing sorry.

Comment: If you can reproduce this in codesandbox.io or something similar I can check

Comment: I found the problem I was using scr instead of src.